# How to load an image from an FTP server in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, ftp

I have a local FTP server which contains list of images.

I want to retrieve those images from that FTP server and display on my app.

Example :

FTP Url : ftp://192.111.01.111/

Image URL : ftp://192.111.01.111/IMG_20190919_153125236.jpg

I've tried something like this :

```
Image.network("//192.168.0.162/IMG_20190917_151246576_HDR.jpg",),
```

But getting the error :

```
Invalid argument(s): Unsupported scheme 'file' in URI file://192.168.0.162/IMG_20190917_151246576_HDR.jpg
```

How to retrieve this image from that server ??

I don't have much idea about FTP servers so if the approach is wrong please suggest the correct approach for loading the files from network.

Answer (score 0):

use [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) from pub.dev

```
Container(
   height: 300,
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
   image: DecorationImage(
      image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(url),
      ),
   ),
);
```